# Check number of active orders in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

[image: DB]
[image: View]
I was trying to retrieve total active orders from my firebase DB. But every time it returns the incorrect output. I am using onClick function to get totalActiveOrder. totalActiveOrder is added when the status of the MEALID is placed or accepted.

Is it possible if I deploy a cloud function and monitor totalActiveOrder in the backend? I was searching online but I can't find any solution.
I have attached the screenshot of my DB and here's my approach

What I am doing is. When the order is placed from the App. that time the status is "placed".
When the restaurant accepts the order then the status changes to "accepted"
When an order is prepared then the status changed to "ready"
When an order is picked by the customer then it changes to "picked"

```
checkActiveOrder = (uid) => {
        let activeOrder = 0
        firebase.database().ref('orders/' + uid + "/").once('value').then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(dataSnap => {
                let status = dataSnap.val().status
                console.log(status)
                if (status === "placed" || status === "accepted") {
                    activeOrder++
                }
            })
            console.log(activeOrder)
        });
    }
    //trigger when button is clicked
    handleClick = async (uid, mealId, type) => {
        this.checkActiveOrder(uid)
        let status = getNextStatus(type);
        function getNextStatus(type) {
            switch (type) {
                case 'placed': return "accepted";
                case 'accepted': return "ready";
                case 'cancel': return "cancel"
                case 'ready': return "picked";
                case 'decline': return "decline";
                default: return null
            }
               await firebase.database().ref('orders/' + uid + "/" + mealId + '/status').set(status);
    }
```

Comment: Can you pls explain a little bit more your use case. I still don't get everything. You try to get the total active orders but in your code you try to get the next `status`. Can you also share your cloud function that you use to increase the total number.

Comment: @TarikHuber check my new edit bro. i don't have a cloud function. I was just wondering if I can have the solution to that

Comment: can you tell exactly what do you mean by getting wrong count *activeOrderCount* is it zero or random value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cloud function to calculete the `totalActiveOrder`. It would look like this:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.countlikechange = functions.database
  .ref("/orders/{orderUid}/{meailID}")
  .onWrite(async (change) => {
    const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child("totalActiveOrder");
    let increment;
    if (change.after.exists()) {
      const { status = "not_set" } = change.after.val();

      if (status === "placed" || status === "accepted") {
        increment = 1;
      } else {
        //Status is not placed or accepted
        increment = -1;
      }
    } else {
      //Order deleted
      increment = -1;
    }

    await countRef.transaction((current) => {
      return (current || 0) + increment;
    });
    functions.logger.log("Counter updated.");
    return null;
  });
```

I'm not sure if you want the totalActiveOrder for each `orderUid`. Let me know if it is so and I will update the code.